RollerCoaster Tycoon 2 stuck minimized on startup
Whenever I launch the Steam version of RollerCoaster Tycoon 2 on my Windows 11 PC, my screen will briefly flash black as if changing resolutions before returning to the desktop. RCT2 will show on my taskbar, but it will be minimized. Trying to focus the game window will open it for a brief second, (sometimes with game audio), before it re-minimizes itself. Running in compatibility mode for Windows XP (Service Pack 2) does not resolve the issue.
How can I run RollerCoaster Tycoon 2 on my Windows 11 PC? Why does the game keep minimizing itself?




Here it is mentioned how exiting explorer.exe solved someone having a similar problem: could you try that?
